# How can I restrict access to certain views and actions in MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

I have three models named Category, Subcategory, and Service. Then, for each of them I created a controller using Entity Framework, which also creates views for them. So, for each of them I have separate Create, Delete, Edit, Details, and Index views. The point is that I have also added a property to my ApplicationUser class, that checks whether a user is admin or not. Namely, I have added this property:

```
public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
```

So, the point is that, I want to check whether the user is admin or not, and act accordingly. If, user is admin, I want him/her to be able to view those views, and simply manipulate data (use the controllers), through those views. But, if he/she is not an admin, I want to show a message that he/she doesn't have authorization to view those pages and change the data. How can I achieve it in MVC? Is it possible?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Well, first, you're going about this wrong. While you can achieve what you want using a property on your user class, you're going to basically have to re-implement what MVC and Identity already give you.

So, instead of leading you further down the rabbit hole, I'm going to pull you back. First, "admin" status should be a role. If a user is an admin, simply give them a role of "Admin" or "Administrator" or whatever you want to call it.

Then, in your controllers/actions you can use the `Authorize` attribute and specify a list of acceptable roles. For example, the following would limit the entire controller to only those in an "Admin" role:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public class FooController : Controller
```

If there's a particular action in that controller that anyone should be able to access, logged in or not, you can still protect the entire controller but use `AllowAnonymous` on the action in question:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public class FooController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult UnprotectedAction()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

You can also just add the `Authorize` attribute directly on your action(s):

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult AdminOnlyAction()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Enjoyed this beautiful answer.

Comment: Loved this beautiful answer.